# Windows Service Log Off

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

As part of our deployment script, our windows service is

1. stopped
2. unregistered
3. registered
4. started

The problem is that sometimes the unregistration requires a log off and log on.

When is this required and is there any way to avoid it?  Currently the script sometimes fails and we are left with having to do this manually.

Comment: How does the script fail? Silently?

Comment: If it's a script then what has it to do with C#?

Comment: Its a windows service written in c#.  The script is really just to explain the situation.  I guess the real question is how do I unregister a service  and have it unregistered without it being 'marked for deletion', which means you need to log off and log back on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to kill Windows service process to avoid it being 'marked for deletion'.

Comment: I guess you mean the Services instance of mmc.exe.  That works!

Comment: I would imagine that actually waiting for the service to actually stop  before proceeding to deregister might be better.

Comment: What I found in the end was that its the services mmc window (not the service itself) which is the issue.  It seems to hold onto a handle for every service.  If you simply close the window it will unregister it correctly, dont need to log off and back on. In a script, you will need to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

From [this page](http://www.rodneybeede.com/How_to_delete_a_Windows_service_without_restarting.html):

It looks as if this will happen when the service is unregistered while still stopping.

The *hack* with the registry key might be a last resort; I would try and wait until the service has stopped.